# Haskell version of double loop

Tags: loops, haskell, functional-programming, duplicates, iteration

I need to do the following in Haskell and can't think of the correct method to do it:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  for (int a=0; a<100; a++)
     foo = (i, a);
```

I also don't want 'duplicates' returned so there's not both (1, 50) and (50, 1). Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I see that you got already some answers to your questions, but make sure to show your attempts on how you tried to solve this yourself next time - this is no "we solve your haskell homework for you"-site but a "we help you solve problems yourself"-site, make sure you put at least as much effort into posting a question as you would somebody expect to answer it

Comment: The loop is unnecessary, because you keep overwriting `foo`: `foo = (99, 99)` alone produces the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```hs
foo :: [(Int, Int)]
foo = [(i, a) | i <- [0..99], a <- [i..99]]
```

Note that there's no mutation in Haskell. Hence, you can't change the value of `foo`. That's why I made it into a list instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use applicative functors and simply do like this;

```
Prelude> (,) <$> [0..2] <*> [0..3]
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

Comment: Doesn't remove duplicates. You'd have to use monads instead.

Comment: ...or repair afterwards, i.e. `filter (uncurry (<=)) $ (,) <$> [0..2] <*> [0..3]`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes that's possible but then it turns out to be a little wasteful i suppose. I guess this approach is not right for the given case. It's my oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all if you do not want duplicates, you can add the constraint `i <= a`. Or you can thus rewrite your code like:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  for (int a=i; a<100; a++)
     foo = (i, a);
```

Next we can use *list comprehension* for this:

```
[(i,a) | i <- [0..99], a <- [i..99]]
```

So we let `i` iterate over `0..99` (both inclusive), and `a` over `i..99`. If we take smaller bounds (6 instead of 99) we obtain:

```
Prelude> [(i,a) | i <- [0..6], a <- [i..6]]
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(0,6),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,5),(5,6),(6,6)]
```

Comment: Mind the direction of your comparisons

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want duplicates, then the loop is really:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  for(int j = i; j < 100; j++)
    something(i, j);
```

Which can be made into Haskell as any of

```
-- raw binds
[0..99] >>= \i ->
  [i..99] >>= \j ->
    return $ something i j

-- do-notation
do i <- [0..99]
   j <- [i..99]
   return $ something i j

-- list comprehension
[ something i j | i <- [0..99], j <- [i..99]]
```