# Haskell nested iteration on the same list starting from first loop

Tags: list, loops, haskell, list-comprehension

I need to do a nested iteration over the same list twice, but the second loop should start where the first one is currently at.

Here's an example using a `for` loop:

```c
List l, tuple_l;

for (int x = 0; x < l.length; x++) {
    for (int y = x; y < l.length; y++) {
        tuple_l.push((l[x], l[y]))
    }
}
```

And here's an example using Python's list comprehension:

```py
[(x, y) for i, x in enumerate(l) for y in l[i:]]
```

I know how to do this iteration in Haskell iterating over the entire array twice...:

```hs
[(x, y) | x <- l, y <- l]
```

...but I'm not sure how I would go to start the second iteration on what comes after `x`. Ideally, it would be able to do something like this:

```hs
[(x, y) | (x:xs) <- l, y <- xs]  -- Doesn't work
```

**Obs.:** I'm aware a similar question was already answered:
[Haskell version of double loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636356/haskell-version-of-double-loop)

However, that approach only works for integer ranges. I guess I could somehow use that approach and access the list items by index, but that's not very haskell/functional-like.

Comment: Not the same, but related: [Iterate over all pair combinations without repetition in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191103/iterate-over-all-pair-combinations-without-repetition-in-haskell).

Comment: @chi I think that's pretty much the same, guess I was just using different terms while searching (nested loops, double loops, etc). I'll mark this post as a duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exploit `tails` as follows:

```
[(x, y) | (x:xs) <- tails l, y <- x:xs, ...]
```

`tails` generates all the possible suffixes, e.g. `tails [1,2,3] == [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3], []]`. Extracting `(x:xs) <- tails l` we therefore get each element `x` and the list of its next elements `xs`. The empty tail `[]` is silently discarded by the list comprehension. Extracting `y <- x:xs` completes the task.

Thanks to laziness, iterating over `tails l` has the same efficiency of iterating over `l` directly. Indeed, no new list is allocated, only pointers to the already existing `l` are used.

Comment: Minor nitpick: it needs to be `y <- x : xs` to get the same behavior as the examples in the question.

Comment: @Noughtmare Indeed, I missed that! Fixed.

Comment: Ah, `tails` was exactly what I was looking for! I think I'll use `[(head xs, y) | xs <- tails l, y <- xs]` instead because the syntax looks a bit nicer.

Comment: I would stay away from `head`. Instead you can use an `@`-pattern: `[(x, y) | xs@(x:_) <- tails, y <- xs]`.

Comment: Huh, is there any issues with `head`? I would imagine it would result in the same operations done in `(x:xs)`.

Comment: @JoãoHaas Note that using `head xs` can crash the program when `xs` is empty. In this case it is safe since `y` is in `xs`, so it is not empty. In general, though, using `head` and `tail` (unlike `tails`) should be avoided in favor of pattern matching, when possible. Note that `(x:xs)<-...` in list comprehensions will never crash, but will silently ignore the empty tail.

Comment: I see. I started learning Haskell recently, so I still don't know all edge cases. That's a good one to remember.

Comment: Really the most [total](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions) solution would be to use [`tails` from Data.List.NonEmpty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:tails): `[(x,y) | x :| xs <- NE.tails l, y <- x : xs, ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward translation of your python code is as follows:

```hs
[(x, y) | (i, x) <- zip [0..] l, y <- drop i l, ...]
```

However, in Python `l[i:]` is a fast operation (O(1)), but in Haskell `drop i l` is slow (O(i)).

As you already seem to try it is better to try to get the tail of the list at the point where the `x` element is. In Haskell you can do that in several ways. Perhaps the easiest is using the `tails` function:

```hs
[(x, y) | (x,xs) <- zip l (tails l), y <- xs, ...]
```

Comment: Yeah, while searching for the response I did see `drop` was an option, but I imagined it wouldn't be as efficient. The `zip` response is nice, although I think I'll just use `head xs` instead of `x` and just use `tails l`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a layer of explicit recursion like this:

```
f xs = case xs of
  [] -> []
  h:t -> [(h, x) | x <- xs] ++ f t
```

If you had done `int y = x + 1;` instead of `int y = x;` in your C code, then you'd use `t` instead of `xs` in the list comprehension in my Haskell code.